# Java JSON parser slows to crawl when JSON contains non-Latin characters

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I do some volunteer work helping out with a website (but my day job is not a programmer/developer). I now need to implement some non-Latin characters (e.g., Japanese characters, Georgian alphabet, etc). Client side is all javascript (with jQuery).

Using jQuery $.post(), I send info to the server. The test JSON looks like this for French:

```
{"myName":"CLTest","myLang":"fr","myData":[{"same":"même","diff":"différent"}]}
```

and like this for Japanese:

```
{"myName":"CLTest","myLang":"ja","myData":[{"same":"同じ","diff":"異なる"}]}
```

and so on. When running with either English, French (which includes accents, as above) or similar, everything works. The server returns an appropriate JSON which is then displayed correctly. With Japanese or Georgian or similar entries, the Java server takes on the order of 5 minutes or so to process the JSON. I don't know how to figure out why this slow down occurs.

If I comment out the JSON parsing code and just return a new JSON, everything is fine. But as soon as I try to parse a JSON containing Japanese or similar non-Latin characters, the huge delay occurs. I've tried two different parsers (json.org and simple-json) and both have this issue. When the 5 or so minutes are up, I can see that the Java app has finished processing the code and has an appropriate JSON to send back, but by this time I get a broken pipe error.

A few more details: the post is received by Apache, which uses ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse to forward to the Java app and return the response. The Java app reads in via an inputstream reader set to use UTF-8, and sends back the reply via DataOutputStream, again writing bytes with UTF-8 encoding. Server is MacOS 10.8 Server.

My problem is that I don't know where to look next to work out what is going on. Should I try yet another JSON parsing library? Roll my own? Have I missed some setting somewhere?

Comment: if you are able to debug, could you send a request that would take this 5 min, and "pause" to see where is it stuck? And maybe... download the Jar code and link the files to it (assuming you are using Eclipse or that you have this functionality) to help you with this.

Comment: I'm just using the command line javac to compile and java to run.

Comment: It's very strange. You need to isolate the smallest section of code that exhibits the problem. For example, does the problem still happen if you read the JSON data from a file instead of from a web request? Does the problem still happen if you try to do other things with the non-Latin text instead of decoding it as JSON?

Comment: I finally tracked this down, and thought I'd own up to my novice erro: I got rid of more and more code, until I found I was confusing bytes and characters: Content-Length is reported in bytes, but when using `c=inFromClient.read(buffer,0,1024)` to get the contents of the JSON, I was comparing `c` (number of characters read) to content length (number of bytes). D'oh! With Japanese, the number of characters is less than the number of bytes, so the loop wouldn't end. Fixing this removed the problem.